# Pandas df.pivot() and pd.pivot_table() with multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to cast a long-format df with multiple indexes into a wide-format df. Why does `df_in.pivot()` fail and/or why is `pd.pivot_table` returning results with a weird hierarchical index so that I can't access the columns I am trying to cast?

```
# input table
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'idx1':range(2)*4, 'idx2':['a']*4+['b']*4, 'field': ['f1']*2+['f2']*2+['f1']*2+['f2']*2, 'value': np.array(range(2)*4)*2+1})
'''
  field  idx1 idx2  value
0    f1     0    a      1
1    f1     1    a      3
2    f2     0    a      1
3    f2     1    a      3
4    f1     0    b      1
5    f1     1    b      3
6    f2     0    b      1
7    f2     1    b      3
'''

# want something like this
pd.DataFrame({'idx1':range(2)*2, 'idx2': ['a']*2+['b']*2, 'a':[1,3]*2, 'b':[1,3]*2})
'''
   a  b  idx1 idx2
0  1  1     0    a
1  3  3     1    a
2  1  1     0    b
3  3  3     1    b
'''

#doesn't work => ValueError: all arrays must be same length
df_in.pivot(index=['idx1','idx2'], columns =['field'])

#doesn't work => weird hierarchical index
pd.pivot_table(df_in, index=['idx1','idx2'], columns =['field'])

'''
          value   
field        f1 f2
idx1 idx2         
0    a        1  1
     b        1  1
1    a        3  3
     b        3  3
'''
# doesn't work => KeyError: 'f1'
pd.pivot_table(df_in, index=['idx1','idx2'], columns =['field'])['f1']

# doesn't work => KeyError: 'f1'
pd.pivot_table(df_in, index=['idx1','idx2'], columns =['field']).reset_index()['f1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the multi-level columns, explicitly specify the value column as a string instead of a list would be sufficient:

```
df_in.pivot_table(values='value', index=['idx1', 'idx2'], columns='field').reset_index()

#field  idx1  idx2  f1  f2
#0        0     a    1   1
#1        0     b    1   1
#2        1     a    3   3
#3        1     b    3   3
```

---

If you do have multi-level columns, you can use tuple to access them, for instance:

```
df_out = df_in.pivot_table(values=['value'], index=['idx1', 'idx2'], columns='field')
```

gives a data frame with multi-level columns, to access `f1` column, you can do:

```
df_out[('value', 'f1')]
```

gives:

```
#idx1  idx2
#0     a       1
#      b       1
#1     a       3
#      b       3
#Name: (value, f1), dtype: int64
```